# Reverse Geocoding in mapbox angular9

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, reverse-geocoding

I've implemented the mapbox concept in angular.I've also added the marker in the map that determines the current location.As of now the iam giving the hardcoded current location(along with latitude and longitude) via a json file.Now i actually want to determine the current location i.e. i want to implement the reverse geocoding concept by giving the latitude and longitude as inputs.How do i go about?

The current code that iam working on looks like this:

```
import { Component,  OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NavigationControl, Map } from 'mapbox-gl';

import {ActivatedRoute, Router,ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import * as mapbox from 'mapbox-gl';

(mapbox as any).accessToken = environment.mapbox.accessToken

@Component({

  selector: 'app-dashboard',

  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  latlng:any;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
          private router:Router)
  {


            this.loadMap();


  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
  }
  loadMap(){

    var latitude=this.latitude;
    var longitude=this.longitude;
    this.latlng=[longitude,latitude]

    var map1=new Map(
      {
        container:'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: { lng: longitude, lat: latitude },
        zoom: 9,
        pitch: 20,
        attributionControl: false
      });
      map1.addControl(
        new NavigationControl({
          showZoom: true,
          showCompass: true
        }),
        'top-right'
      );



      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../assets/images/truck.png')";
      el.style.backgroundSize='cover';
      el.style.width = '50px';
      el.style.height = '50px';  
      el.style.marginTop='-35px'
      el.style.cursor='pointer';



      new mapbox.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(this.latlng)
      .setPopup(new mapbox.Popup({offset:25})
      .setHTML('<p>'+this.orderItem.current_location+'</p>'))
      .addTo(map1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current position using the Geolocation control:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

You would have to call it with options, such as these:

```js
  var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
  };
```

You would have to implement the error and success callbacks:

```js
function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
      }
```

On success you can make use of the returned coordinates. You could for example use them in a reverse geocoding request.

```js
function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;

    console.log('Your current position is:');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
      }
```

Please also see this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Let me know if something is unclear!

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.Since iam using maps from Mapbox.They have their own classes and functions that would fetch me the location when latitude and longitude are given as inputs.But i've no clue as to how those would work